# В цикле записать значения контролам из ресурса

Tags: c++-cli

```
 private:System::Void ChangeLanguage(String^ lang) {

     CultureInfo^ newCultureInfo = gcnew CultureInfo(lang);

     ComponentResourceManager^ resources = gcnew 
ComponentResourceManager(this->GetType());


 resources->ApplyResources(this, "$this", newCultureInfo); 
 resources->ApplyResources(ReadBtn, "ReadBtn", newCultureInfo);

 for each (Control^ c in this->Controls)
 {
     resources->ApplyResources(c, c->Name, newCultureInfo);
 }
 }
```

Я пытаюсь из файлов ресурсов достать значения текста и присвоить их контролам

```
 resources->ApplyResources(ReadBtn, "ReadBtn", newCultureInfo);
```

Так меняется, если брать каждый отдельно, а в цикле не хочет

Comment: @Abyx То есть на плюсы не переведешь ?

Comment: Ваш код написан не на C#

Comment: Коллеги, но это ж явно не учебное задание.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно угадал, вам нужно вот что:

```
for each (Control^ c in this->Controls)
{
    resources->ApplyResources(c, c->Name, newCultureInfo);
}
```

(Проверить не могу, т. к. вы не дали компилируемый пример.)

И да, результирующий код не на C++, а на C++/CLI (это кардинально разные вещи).

---

Замечание:

Ваш первоначальный цикл неправильный, он не находит вложенные контролы. Можно сделать, например, так:

```
System::Void ChangeLanguageRec(ComponentResourceManager^ resources, CultureInfo^ ci, Control^ c)
{
    resources->ApplyResources(c, c->Name, ci);
    for each (Control^ child in c->Controls)
        ChangeLanguageRec(resources, ci, child);
}

System::Void ChangeLanguage(String^ lang)
{
    ComponentResourceManager^ resources = gcnew ComponentResourceManager(this->GetType());
    CultureInfo^ newCultureInfo = gcnew CultureInfo(lang);
    ChangeLanguageRec(resources, newCultureInfo, this);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, поправил вопрос

Comment: @PabloMurena: А с таким кодом, как в вопросе, что не так? Можете посмотреть, чему равно `ReadBtn->Name`?

Comment: ReadBtn->Name = "ReadBtn"

Comment: все вроде бы правильно но не хочет меняться

Comment: @PabloMurena: Очень странно. Вы уверены, что без цикла таки работает?

Comment: ДА уверен к коде который в вопросе есть два контрола которые не в цикле, так они меняют значения . пробовал и с другими контролами получается, а в цикле не работает

Comment: @PabloMurena: Тогда дайте воспроизводящий пример.

Comment: Добавил новых контролов на форму и заметил что не менятся только то что находится в TabControl и MenuStrip а все что просто на форме так в нем меняется

Comment: то-есть то что находится во вложении не хочет инициализироваться, а так цикл рабочий

Comment: пробовал в ресурсах менять на tabControlParams.tabPage2.ReadBtn.Text  ничего не дало

Comment: @PabloMurena: А, понятно. Ну так значит ваш первоначальный цикл на C# был неправильный.

Comment: @PabloMurena: Посмотрите в обновление.

Comment: Спасибо, работает) все кроме MenuStrip. попробую разобраться, а если нет то вне цикла сделаю ) Спасибо)

Comment: @PabloMurena: Хм, может, `MenuStrip` недоступно как (рекурсивный) дочерний элемент? // Пожалуйста!